# Power automate json

Tags: json, power-automate

I am making flow with power automate which is taking email body and then i am trying to choose specific details from that.

Flow is:

1.Catching email

2.Making email html to text

3.Making newline and splitNewLines

4. Filtering for array.

But my problem is that my Json is coming with one big strings.

```
  {
     "body": [
           "Customer: James",
           "CustomerId: 1234",
           "Address: Street 123",
           "Phone: 123455123"
            ]
  }
```

So they are not coming like this:

```
{
 "body": [
       "Customer": "James",
       "CustomerId": "1234",
       "Address": "Street 123",
       "Phone": "123455123"
        ]
}
```

Anyone has idea how to fix this?

Comment: I guess your software is creating this JSON, right? If so, share it. Otherwise give some details. For now it seems evident your algorithm needs to insert a few quotes more creating a valid JSON.

Comment: Its creating JSON.  And this is format what i get out :

Comment: {
    "body": [
        "[http://www.f1.com/logo.png",
        "LÄHETE",
        "OrderID: 8154747",
        "Reference: 31563JLH",
        "Customer: XML Customer Company",
        "-------------------------------------------------------------",
        "Address: Street 123",
        "Customer Oy",
        "91230 Boston",
        "German",
        "SendingAddress:",
        "Company CO",
        "FinalCustomer: Company CO",
        "Street 123",
        "James Bond",
        "12324 New York",
        "USA"
    ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Add a Compose action and write expression to adjust your JSON

e.g.

```
replace(outputs('JSONoutput'), ':', '":"')
```